# Python - Adding a digit to a integer

Tags: python, integer

how do i add a digit to an integer in python ?

```
value = 9

#add a 9 to "value" to get 99

print(value)
```

So i want the console to return :

```
99
```

I tryed to do

```
value.append(9)
```

but it didnt work

Comment: Yes, you have to use math.  What number would you add to 9 to get 99?

Comment: Multiply it by `10`, then add the new digit value.  For example, if you have `123` and want to add `6` to the end, you can use `10*123 + 6` to get `1236`.  It's just arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could convert your number to a string, add those together, and then convert it back into an integer. Something like

`var1 = "9"`
`var2 = var1 + var1`
`convertedAnswer = int(var2)`
`print(convertedAnswer)`

could work?

Comment: Tysm ! It worked !

Answer (score 0):

You can convert int to str, concatenate the strings, and the convert back to int:

```
value = 9

add = 9

print(int(str(value) + str(add)))
```

Comment: Shortest solution: `print(int(f"{value}{add}"))` @Tom Sometimes it is not worth complicating the matter and using the simplest solution.

Comment: @TomKarzes meh, I'd say profile it before calling it "rediculous".

Comment: @TomKarzes maybe you're right. but think if you have to add an integer instead of a digit, the solution wouldn't look so ridiculous (btw that is what I was thinking for some reason when proposing this)

Comment: @TomKarzes well, `10*123+6` will just result in a bytecode for retrieving a constant. You want something like: `timeit.timeit("10*x+y", setup="x=123; y=6")` which gives me `0.07322674599999957` and compare that to: `timeit.timeit('int(f"{x}{y}")', setup="x=123; y=6")` which gives me `0.29948458500000186` so about a 4X speedup